# Print and save .txt

Tags: c, text, save, printf

I'm trying to do 3 things:

1. Load a .txt file
2. Print the contents of the file to a console.
3. Save it again with another name.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

char text[500]; /* Create a character array that will store all of the text in the file */
char line[100]; /* Create a character array to store each line individually */

 int  inpChar; 

FILE *file; /* Create a pointer to the file which will be loaded, to allow access to it */
char fileName[100]; /* Create a character array to store the name of the file the user want to load */


do {
printf("enter menu: [l]oad - [s]ave - [p]rint\n");
scanf("%c", &inpChar);
    } 
    while((inpChar != 'l') && (inpChar != 's') && (inpChar !="p"));

if((inpChar == 'l'))
{
 printf("Enter the name of the file containing ship information: ");
}
scanf("%s", fileName);

/*Try to open the file specified by the user. Use error handling if file cannot be found*/
file = fopen(fileName, "r"); /* Open the file specified by the user in 'read' mode*/
if(file == NULL){
    printf("The following error occurred.\n");
}
else {
    printf("File loaded. \n"); /* Display a message to let the user know 

                          * that the file has been loaded properly */

}

 do {
printf("enter menu: [l]oad - [s]ave - [p]rint\n");
scanf("%c", &inpChar);
    } 


while((inpChar != 'l') && (inpChar != 's') && (inpChar !='p'));
if((inpChar == 'p'))
{
file = fopen(fileName, "r");
fprintf(file, "%s", line);
fclose(file);

}

return 0;
}
```

I am missing the printed text on the console panel; it didn't work and the save option is missing from the code. What should I do?

Comment: `file = fopen(fileName, "r"); if(file == NULL){
    perror( filename );
}`

Comment: Define "it didn't work"..

Comment: Could you reduce the code sample to only contain the code which doesn't work, without clutter like the user interface?

Comment: I see many problems in your code, too many to post specifics. You should break the problem down better... write a program with one function to load your file (using a fixed file name at first). Make it work to your satisfaction (note the code you pasted makes exactly _zero_ reads of an input file!). Then modify the program with another function that prints the contents to the screen. (Your code makes no effort to do this either, which is good considering you haven't read the file yet.) Finally, a routine to save the file elsewhere. Once these all work, then think about prompting what to do.

Comment: ok but it still the same problem with the print funktion !.

Comment: ok hten what should I do?

Comment: ichanged the code to                                                  file = fopen(fileName, "r"); /* Open the file specified by the user in 'read' mode*/
    
    if(file == NULL){
     perror( fileName );
    }
    else {
        printf("File loaded. \n");                                                              but it still the same problem with [p]rint

Comment: @user2068108 My comment has nothing to do with the problem you describe, but is describing a better way to report an error.

Comment: @William Pursell , I know but it works better thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following makes no sense:

```
file = fopen(fileName, "r");
fprintf(file, "%s", line);
```

If you open a file for reading, why are you trying to write to it?  You want to read from the file (`man fgets`) and then write to stdout.

Comment: Read lines from the file and print them to stdout.  Use `fgets` to read a line from the file, then use `printf` to print it.

Comment: if((inpChar == 'p'))
 { 

 fgets ( line ,9999,file);
 printf(line,file);
 
 fclose(file);

Comment: @Haido  If your current code is only reading one line, consider putting it inside a loop.

Comment: I tried with while loop so i works now , thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 0):

Problems are in line 10:

```
int inpChar;
```

should be

```
char  inpChar;
```

mistake in line 23:

```
while((inpChar != 'l') && (inpChar != 's') && (inpChar !="p"));
```

should be

```
'p'
```

You have to read file into an array.
Here is a primitive way to do it if the file isn't longer than 10000 chars.

```
char all[10000];
fread (all ,1,9999,file);
printf("%s", all);
```

A better way to read your file would be  line by line using [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).

Comment: ok but it still the same problem , I want to first load the file then when I enter p the text file showing on the consol, so when I load the text file and print it  I get  " ------- " , not what I have in the text file.!

Comment: Yes it worsks now Thank you very much ;)

Comment: Butt how can I save  it again  with another text file name?